# ¿Por que no envia datos mi app de java a php utilizando json?

Tags: php, java, json

Tengo un problema y ojalá alguien me indicara por qué no recibe mi documento php lo que le mando desde java. Estoy utilizando JSON y no entiendo cuál es el error, estoy utilizando un servidor (XAMPP), tiene los controladores necesarios el proyecto de java y cree en el servidor la carpeta "servicios" y ahí guarde mi carpeta archivo "index.php", como lo  muestra mi ruta en la parte de abajo. No sé si ahí estaría el error.

Nota:
Tengo desactivado el firewall y el antivirus,

De ante mano muchas gracias.

---

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;   
import java.io.*;    
import java.net.*;    
import java.util.*;    

public class JSONEX01 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Map <String,String> datosEnv = new HashMap<String,String>();            
        datosEnv.put("nombre", "Miguel");            
        datosEnv.put("apellido", "Olvera");            
        datosEnv.get("apellido");
        
        Gson gson = new Gson();
       
        String jsonOutput = gson.toJson(datosEnv);            
        System.out.println(datosEnv.get("apellido"));
        
        try{
           
            jsonOutput = URLEncoder.encode("key","UTF-8")+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(jsonOutput, "UFF-8");
          
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost/servicios/index.php");          
            URLConnection con = (URLConnection) url.openConnection();    
            con.setDoOutput(true);
        
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(jsonOutput);                        
            wr.flush();
        
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String str = buf.readLine();
                    
            while(str != null){                
                System.out.println(str+"pero pues entre");                
                str = buf.readLine();
            }
        
        }catch(Exception e){                
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());            
        }           
    }       
}
```

***************************** codigo en php ***************

```
<?php
    
    $se = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST["key"]));
    var_dump($_POST["key"]);
    echo "nombre: ".$se->nombre."\n";
    echo "Apellido".$se->apellido."\n";
    echo "fin de la transmision !!! ";
?>
```

Comment: Te envía algún mensaje de error?

Comment: ¿Codificación `UFF-8`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la linea donde asignas el valor para `jsonOutput` al final agregas `UFF-8` y es `UTF-8`

```
jsonOutput = URLEncoder.encode("key", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(jsonOutput, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: ah no inventes que idiota, muchas gracias jajaj